# HDIV - How to modify the URL param values in Ajax request?

Tags: ajax, parameters, hdiv

I am trying to integrate HDIV into my existing application. But I am stuck in solving the below problem.

**Use Case:** 
1. I have a big form with huge number of fields. When I change a value in a drop down, I make an Ajax call by passing the selected value as a URL parameter.
ex:

1. $.get("http:://ajaxurl?dynamicParam=1", function(data) {/*Render new HTML Content  into existing page*/});
2. $.get("http:://ajaxurl?dynamicParam=2", function(data) {/Render new HTML Content  into existing page**/});
   etc.

**Problem:**
As i select values in the drop down, different values are passed in the ajax param and HDIV throws an INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE Error.

Only solution I can see is that I need to submit the whole Form with _MODIFIED_HDIV_STATE value.

But, I cant submit the whole form (Which has hell lot of data) in order to pass only one value as part of my Ajax call. Also, I cant exclude the param to bypass HDIV validation as I have the same use case across my application in numerous places.

Is there a way to pass the modified HDIV state as part of the AJAX call as we can do in the FORM submit ? Or please suggest me a way to solve this.

Please help me out to solve this issue. (I am stuck through half way after integrating HDIV into most of my application)

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky situation. You can be in one of these situations:

- If you can NOT know in the server side the values of the parameter, you can only define that parameter as a *start parameter* and skip the validation for that parameter:

if you want to skip the validation for all the views:

```
<hdiv:startParameters>parameter1</hdiv:startParameters>
```

if you want to skip the validation for the views you want:

```
<hdiv:paramsWithoutValidation>
    <hdiv:mapping url="url1" parameters="parameter1" />
</hdiv:paramsWithoutValidation>
```

- If you can know in the server side the values of the parameter:

There are two options:

- Generate all the posible links, one for each value of the parameter and choose by JavaScript the link you want.
- Do the AJAX call through a form with a parameter. This parameter would be a select with all the posible values. (Recommended option)

I hope it helps.